# do I still need to block attacks on my server once I lock it down by ip?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have a public dedicated server that clients log in to via RDP. I am using rdpguard to block bad RDP logins attempts on my server. Recently, I locked it down to only allow specific IP addresses through Windows firewall.

Do I still need a program like rdpguard to block these attacks or can I remove it and free up the resources rdpguard uses? Is it serving a purpose now or is the firewall preventing them from even attempting to login?

I do not have a hardware firewall and cannot get one for my scenario so please, avoid this topic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Firewall doesn't necessarily "block" your machine from brute force attacks on TCP port 3389. It just filters via an access control list for those you are permitting to use that port /service. There are many ways the RDP service can be attacked even with a Windows firewall. If your not already using SSL, I recommend you do so as detailed in this [howto from technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458357.aspx).

I would keep RDPGuard on your system as a "poor-man's" [defense-in-depth](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/warfare/defense-depth-impractical-strategy-cyber-world-33896)

Comment: great thx for the link and info!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're denying access to all but your client's IP, then all rdpguard would be doing is blocking bad login attempts from your client.

It's probably not necessary to keep running, but then again, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Are they even able to attempt to login if they are not on the whitelist? If so, then I would prob leave it running.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall really only does an effective job addressing up to layer 3 while you should be looking all the way up to layer 7, application layer filtering. Technet states [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755604%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that:

> With the exception of some File Transfer Protocol (FTP) traffic, Windows Firewall does not use Application layer information to statefully filter traffic.

While that article is for Server 2003 the same is true for 2008. While I've not used rdpgaurd, it appears to only do log monitoring rather than true traffic inspection.

To answer your question:
The amount of security implemented should be proportional to the value of the data you are protecting. For an internal server, layer 3 protection may be sufficient but for a public facing server you should implement as much security as you can without hindering operation. So in my opinion, yes, if you care about your clients and your reputation as a service provider then you need to protect your external facing systems. Moreover you should be using something specifically designed for such a scenario.  Without knowing your operational parameters and since you stated that hardware is out of the question, take a look at Microsoft's Forefront line of products.  Otherwise, most of the major network/security (McAfee, Cisco, F5, Checkpoint, etc.) vendors have some software solution depending on your budget.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind, RDPGuard solely relies on the Windows Event Log in order to block incoming IP addresses. There are various of ways to bypass this, which means that the app will not pick up the IP address of the attacker and will not do anything about it.

It would be best for you to rather change the RDP default port(3389) to something else.